# Images within divs are being cut off due to height differences, how to display them entirely?

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

My site consists of 3 divs (blueish boxes) lined in a row. Each div contains an image and either 3 or 4 lines of text (wrapped in `p` tags)

The problem is that the images are not being shown entirely within the divs. Instead the sides are being cut off and this obscures the image. In the following demo you can see the divs containing cut-off images, and then the full-size images below them for reference. [Demo here](http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/indextest.html)

Please note that the source images are different heights, yet they do *not* disrupt the even alignment of the lines across each div as shown below. I'd like this feature to remain:

[image: Screeny1]

How do I make the images display entirely within the div (including feathering effect)?  I've created a mockup below of the ideal solution:

[image]

The code for the first div is:

```
<a href="htada">    
<p class="vignette" style="background-image:url(http://www.luminouseyegfx.com/prolookwp/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/jet_ski-320x212.jpg)"></p>
<p class="redbox">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="titlebox">Demo</p>
<p class="locationbox">Demo</p>
<p class="pricebox">Demo</p>
                  <!-- END OF SINGLE LISTING -->
</a>
```

and it's CSS:

```
.mainbox a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0 0.5em 0;
width: 28%;
background: #E7E6F2;
box-shadow: 0 50px 0 #E7E6F2 , 0 100px #E7E6F2 , 0 150px #E7E6F2;
border-top: 1em solid white;
padding: 0.5em;
margin-top: 151px;
height: 700px;
}
```

You can see the image is produced using a div with style of `background-image:url(http:// ...` and that div's CSS is:

```
.vignette {
         width: 90%;
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
       margin-bottom:1%;
       margin-top: 4%;
        box-shadow: 15px 15px 40px #E7E6F2 inset,-15px -15px 40px #E7E6F2 inset;
        height: 290px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the images the background, why not just add them as a sub-element of the `<p>`'s?

```
<p class="vignette">
    <img src="..."/>
<p>
```

Then you can apply CSS to the image too, and make it the full width of the container.

```
.vignette img
{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The z-index and position will place the image below the box-shadow of the parent.

---

An alternative would be to do this, but place the box-shadow on the img, as opposed to the p.

```
.vignette img
{
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 15px 15px 40px #e736f2, inset -15px -15px 40px #e7e6f2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, I changed my demo to reflect your first solution, but the images aren't displayed now. Here's the source code: view-source:http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/indextest.html   and here's the css file: http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/main.css

Comment: Yes, because you have `z-index: -1;` in the CSS declaration for `vignette img` class.

Comment: Isn't that what David told me to do in his answer?   .vignette img
{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}